# refresh the state when popping

Tags: flutter, navigation, page-refresh

i am using a Future builder to set up a profile for my users and they get to edit the info in a second page. but when they submit Navigator.pop(context) is called but nothing changes on the first screen. it only refresh the state if i leave the page and come back to it! is there a way to force the screen refresh?

```
 User user = User(
    id: widget.user.id,
    name: _name,
    profileImageUrl: _profileImageUrl,
    bio: _bio,
    email: _email,
    webAddress: _webAddress,
    tel: _tel,
    location: _location,

  );
  DatabaseService.updateUser(user);


  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

this is what my submit button does

Comment: `Navigator.push()` returns a `Future` - you have to listen when it completes and call `setState` there

Comment: thank you @pskink . i am quite new to flutter. is there a way you can show me how its done? best regards

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @pskink in the comments `Navigator.pop()` will return a Future. You can listen for it to complete and then call `setState` to rebuild your widget

```dart
Navigator.push().then((value)=> setState((){});
```

Now, this only works if your data on the view and edit page are from the same source. If you are just passing the original values to edit the page and making changes there then no matter what your previous page might not be updated. In that case, you can return the updated data from the edit page or use a state management approach to listen to changes

Comment: `push` returns a `Future`, not `pop`